# How do I delete a directory in Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, delete

I am using Centos as my server OS and in my desktop I have a directory called "john", I need delete it via a command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
rm -f -r john
```

It will recursively delete *john* directory even if it contains files or subdirectories.

Comment: You can have `-f` and `-r` together. Like this : `rm -rf`.

Answer (score 2):

If the directory is empty then you can just do `rmdir john`.

Or you can force it with `rm -r john`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -r ${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR:-$HOME/Desktop}/john
```

XDG_DESKTOP_DIR is an environment variable that contains the path to the desktop directory. If it's not set, we fall back to $HOME/Desktop.

Comment: my account is [root@localhost]# if it is so how can I remove My desktop directory. I am little bit confused with this ${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR:-

Comment: @John why on earth are you logging in as root for normal operations?

Comment: ok tell me delete desktop directory logging as normal user